# When I activate wp/jQuery scrollbar plugin in my website, twitter widget don't show any tweet

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter, scroll

I am working on a website. For my design it's necessary to use custom content scrollbar. That's why i used Jquery Custom Content Scroller and also WP Awesome Scrollbar. I also used a twitter widget to show tweets.

But the problem is when i use one of the two plugins(Jquery Custom Content Scroller/WP Awesome Scrollbar) twitter widget don't show any content. I didn't find out any solution for this problem. Here is the website [link](http://jecorcreative.com/david). On the home page right side after about content there is a area for recent tweets.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the JavaScript in the Custom Code Slider is conflicting with the twitter widget as it loads and and then disappears. There is no error in the console unforuntaly. I seen there was a 302 and 304 HTTP Reponse from Twitter though which I can't explain why without logging into the twitter account + having all the keys.

A work around I suggest is installing [JetPack](http://jetpack.me/) by Automatic if you haven't already done so, and use their WordPress Widget as it is a lot more reliable that the 3rd party ones. This should work.

I have looked at your site and you source code and the jetpack version works... further I tested it on a couple of browsers. See the image:

[image: David Alexan Bullock]

Comment: I used jetpack wordpress widget for twitter timeline. But it didn't work. You can see on my site.
BTW thanks.. @ham-sandwich

Comment: I inspected the source code and see you have added JetPack Twitter. I see it showing up on multiple browsers. See image.

Comment: At last i use css for styling scroll bar without using plugin... :) 
The image you add to your answer that is the result after i use just css for scrollbar... :)
But firefox doesn't support scrollbar style... :(

Comment: Maybe, but you still implemented JetPack and striped out the previous plugin.